# Default external encoding in ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby, encoding

I heard that Ruby 2.1 uses UTF-8 as default encoding. But `Encoding.default_external` returns `US-ASCII`. Is this a usual case, or suggesting something wrong with my environment?

Comment: I think it is from 2.0, not 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 is used as the default encoding of the **source file** since Ruby 2.0. Note that it's not the same as the external encoding. [`Encoding.default_external`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external) depends on the locale, for instance, `LANG` environment variable on Unix.

> The default external encoding is initialized by the locale or `-E` option.